# How to capitalize the last letter of each word in a string

Tags: javascript, string

I am still rather new to JavaScript and I am having an issue of getting the first character of the string inside the array to become uppercase.

I have gotten to a point where I have gotten all the texted lowercase, reversed the text character by character, and made it into a string. I need to get the first letter in the string to uppercase now.

```js
function yay () {
  var input = "Party like its 2015";

  return input.toLowerCase().split("").reverse().join("").split(" ");
  for(var i = 1 ; i < input.length ; i++){
    input[i] = input[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + input[i].substr(1);
  }   
}

console.log(yay());
```

I need the output to be "partY likE itS 2015"

Comment: Do you realize that no code executes in your function AFTER the `return` statement?  What is the desired output?

Comment: You have a loop inside your function, but you return on the line before that so it never runs.

Comment: What is the output you're trying to generate?

Comment: The code you've shown doesn't have any arrays in it.

Comment: "Party Like Its 2015" - is this desired output?

Comment: Instead of `return xxx` I think you want `input = xxx`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of returning the result splitting and reversing the string, you need to assign it to `input`. Otherwise, you return from the function before doing the loop that capitalizes the words.
Then after the `for` loop you should return the joined string.

Also, since you've reverse the string before you capitalize, you should be capitalizing the *last* letter of each word. Then you need to reverse the array before re-joining it, to get the words back in the original order.

```js
function yay () {
  var input = "Party like its 2015";

  input = input.toLowerCase().split("").reverse().join("").split(" ");
  for(var i = 1 ; i < input.length ; i++){
    var len = input[i].length-1;
    input[i] = input[i].substring(0, len) + input[i].substr(len).toUpperCase();
  }
  return input.reverse().join(" ");
}

alert(yay());
```

Comment: @dave The question says _reversed the text character by character_

Comment: @dave I am sorry if I wasn't clear enough. I apologize and I will try to be more specific in the future.

Answer (score 4):

Frustrating that you posted your initial question without disclosing the desired result.  Lots of turmoil because of that.  Now, that the desired result is finally clear - here's an answer.

You can lowercase the whole thing, then split into words, rebuild each word in the array by uppercasing the last character in the word, then rejoin the array:

```js
function endCaseWords(input) {
    return input.toLowerCase().split(" ").map(function(item) {
        return item.slice(0, -1) + item.slice(-1).toUpperCase();
    }).join(" ");
}

document.write(endCaseWords("Party like its 2015"));
```

Here's a step by step explanation:

1. Lowercase the whole string
2. Use `.split(" ")` to split into an array of words
3. Use `.map()` to iterate the array
4. For each word, create a new word that is the first part of the word added to an uppercased version of the last character in the word
5. `.join(" ")` back together into a single string
6. Return the result

---

You could also use a regex replace with a custom callback:

```js
function endCaseWords(input) {
    return input.toLowerCase().replace(/.\b/g, function(match) {
      return match.toUpperCase();
    });
}

document.write(endCaseWords("Party like its 2015"));
```

FYI, there are lots of things wrong with your original code.  The biggest mistake is that as soon as you `return` in a function, no other code in that function is executed so your `for` loop was never executed.

Then, there's really no reason to need to `reverse()` the characters because once you split into words, you can just access the last character in each word.

Answer (score 3):

You can use regular expression for that:

```
input.toLowerCase().replace(/[a-z]\b/g, function (c) { return c.toUpperCase() });
```

Or, if you can use [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), simply:

```
input.toLowerCase().replace(/[a-z]\b/g, c => c.toUpperCase())
```

Comment: Nice solution. Although we both misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I would do:

1. Split the sentence on the space character
2. Transform the resulting array using .map to capitalize the first character and lowercase the remaining ones
3. Join the array on a space again to get a string

```js
function yay () {
  var input = "Party like its 2015";
  return input.split(" ").map(function(item) {
    return item.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + item.slice(1).toLowerCase();
  }).join(" ");
}

console.log(yay());
```

Answer (score 0):

Some ugly, but working code:

```js
 var text = "Party like its 2015";
  //partY likE itS 2015
  function yay(input) {

    input = input.split(' ');

    arr = [];

    for (i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
      new_inp = input[i].charAt(0).toLowerCase() + input[i].substring(1, input[i].length - 1) + input[i].charAt(input[i].length - 1).toUpperCase();
      arr.push(new_inp);
    }

    str = arr.join(' ');
    return str;

  }

  console.log(yay(text));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`ucwords`](http://phpjs.org/functions/ucwords/) from PHP.js. It's quite simple, actually.

```
String.prototype.ucwords = function() {
    return (this + '')
        .replace(/^([a-z\u00E0-\u00FC])|\s+([a-z\u00E0-\u00FC])/g, function($1) {
        return $1.toUpperCase();
    });
}

var input = "Party like its 2015";
input = input.charAt(0).toLowerCase() + input.substr(1);
input = input.split('').reverse().join('').ucwords();
input = input.split('').reverse().join('');
```

Note: I modified their function to be a `String` function so method chaining would work.

Answer (score 0):

```
function yay(str)
{
let arr = str.split(' ');
let farr = arr.map((item) =>{
  let x = item.split('');
  let len = x.length-1
  x[len] = x[len].toUpperCase();
  x= x.join('')
  return x;
})
return farr.join(' ')

}


var str = "Party like its 2015";
let output = yay(str);

console.log(output) /// "PartY likE itS 2015"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split and then map over the array perform uppercase logic and retun by joining string.

```js
let string = "Party like its 2015";

const yay = (string) => {
    let lastCharUpperCase = string.split(" ").map((elem) => {
         elem = elem.toLowerCase();
        return elem.replace(elem[elem.length - 1], elem[elem.length - 1].toUpperCase())
    })
    return lastCharUpperCase.join(" ");
}

console.log(yay(string))
```